# What is the most effcient way to replace values in a specific column of a table for this specific scenario?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a table in my database called `t1` (extract of only 2 columns shown below):

```
 ResaID       StayDate
 100          2020-02-03
 100          2020-02-04
 100          2020-02-05
 120          2020-04-06
 120          2020-04-07
 120          2020-04-08
 120          2020-04-09
 120          2020-04-10
```

I need to change the dates in the `StayDate` column based on the following information (extract shown exactly as provided):

```
 ID        StartDate       EndDate
 100       2020-06-04      2020-06-06
 120       2021-03-01      2021-03-05
```

I have started writing my T-SQL query as follows (but it is getting quite tedious as I have to do it for more than 100 ResaID!):

```
USE MyDatabase

UPDATE t1

SET StayDate = CASE WHEN ResaID = 100 and StayDate = '2020-02-03' THEN '2020-06-04'
WHEN ResaID = 100 and StayDate = '2020-02-04' THEN '2020-06-05'
WHEN ResaID = 100 and StayDate = '2020-02-05' THEN '2020-06-06'
...    

ELSE StayDate

END
```

Is there a more efficient way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you have a separate table for date ranges ?

Comment: Not yet but I can create a table for those date ranges.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the link. I will definitely have a look.

Comment: I'm working on an answer, but have a couple of question. You mentioned your `t1` table has other columns. In these "auxiliary" columns, is the data unique to ResaID and StayDate, or just ResaID? Also, will the length of stay be the same every time? As in ResaID has 3 stay dates and also has a 3 day range provided in the new table. Is that always consistent, or could the updated data contain, shorter/longer stays?

Comment: @AaronHughes Yes the data in the other column is unique to the ResaID and StayDate. The length of stay is the same for around 90% of the ResaIDs. I will use my existing method to deal with the remaining 10 %.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *recursive* approach  :

```
with r_cte as (
     select id, convert(date, startdate) as startdate, convert(date, enddate) as enddate
     from ( values (100, '2020-06-04', '2020-06-06'), 
                   (120, '2021-03-01', '2021-03-03')
          ) t(id, startdate, enddate)
     union all
     select id, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
     from cte c
     where startdate < enddate
), r_cte_seq as (
     select r.cte.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by startdate) as seq
     from r_cte 
), cte_seq as (
     select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by ResaID order by staydate) as seq
     from t1
)
update cs
       set cs.staydate = rc.startdate
from cte_seq cs inner join
     r_cte_seq rc
     on rc.id = cs.ResaID and rc.seq = cs.seq;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I am a bit confused with the aliases used in your solution. Assuming the table I need to update is called t1, where does it go in that T-SQl query?

Comment: I am also confused with "cte c" and " r.cte" in the query.

Comment: @user3115933. . . `cte_seq` is updateable cte, you can use `t1`  inside it. Check updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to this problem. I would use a numbers table to generate a record for each date in the new range for each reservation ID. I would then partition this data by reservation ID, ordered by the date. Doing the same partition logic on the existing data will allow records to be properly joined together.

I would then do a `DELETE` operation followed by an `INSERT` operation. This would leave you with the appropriate amount of records. The only manual thing that would need to be done is to populate the auxiliary data for reservations with expanded date ranges. I expanded one of your new ranges to show this scenario.

I've marked where the setup for this demo ends in the code below. Everything below that is my intended solution that should be able to be implemented with your real tables.

```
 --Ranges Table
 DECLARE @ranges TABLE
 (
    ID INT
    ,StartDate DATETIME
    ,EndDate DATETIME
 )

 DECLARE @t1 TABLE
 (
    ResaID INT
    ,StayDate DATETIME
    ,ColA INT
    ,ColB NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ColC BIT
 )

 INSERT INTO @t1
 (
    ResaID
    ,StayDate
    ,ColA
    ,ColB
    ,ColC
 )
 VALUES
 (100, '2020-02-03', 1, 'A', 0)
 ,(100, '2020-02-04', 100, 'B', 1)
 ,(100, '2020-02-05', 255, 'C', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-06', 34, 'D', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-07', 67, 'E', 0)
 ,(120, '2020-04-08', 87, 'F', 0)
 ,(120, '2020-04-09', 545, 'G', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-10', 288, 'H', 0)

 INSERT INTO @ranges
 (
    ID
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
 )
 VALUES
 (100, '2020-06-04', '2020-06-07')
 ,(120, '2021-03-01', '2021-03-05')

--END DEMO SETUP

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #numbers
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #newRecords



--GENERATE NUMBERS TABLE
    ;WITH e1(n) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ), -- 10
    e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
    e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 AS b), -- 100*100
    e4(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e3 CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 5 n FROM e1) AS b)  -- 5*10000

     SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as Num
     INTO #numbers
     FROM e4 
     ORDER BY n;


 ;with oldData --PARTITION THE EXISTING RECORDS
 AS
 (
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResaID  ORDER BY STAYDATE) as ResPartID
    FROM @t1
 )
 ,newRanges --GENERATE YOUR NEW RANGES AND PARITITION
 AS
 (
 select
    r.ID
    ,CAST(n.num as DATETIME) as StayDate
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n.num) as ResPartID
 from @ranges r
    inner join #numbers n on CAST(r.StartDate as INT) <= n.Num  AND CAST(r.EndDate as INT) >= n.Num
)

SELECT n.ID
      ,n.StayDate
      ,o.ColA
      ,o.ColB
      ,o.ColC
into #newRecords
FROM newRanges n
    left join oldData o on n.ID = o.ResaID and n.ResPartID = o.ResPartID

--DELETE OLD RECORDS
DELETE t
FROM @t1 t
    inner join @ranges r on t.ResaID = r.ID

--INSERT NEW DATA
INSERT INTO @t1
(
    ResaID
    ,StayDate
    ,ColA
    ,ColB
    ,ColC
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,StayDate
    ,ColA
    ,ColB
    ,ColC
FROM #newRecords

SELECT * FROM @t1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code converts the `t1` dates into ranges and then uses the corresponding `range` dates to calculate new `StayDate` values. You can swap out the final `select` for one of the commented statements to see what is going on in the CTEs. The final `select` can be replaced with an `update` if you want to change the original table data.

```
 -- Thanks to Aaron Hughes for setting up the sample data.
 -- I changed the   DateTime   columns to   Date .

 --Ranges Table
 DECLARE @ranges TABLE
 (
    ID INT
    ,StartDate DATE
    ,EndDate DATE
 )

 DECLARE @t1 TABLE
 (
    ResaID INT
    ,StayDate DATE
    ,ColA INT
    ,ColB NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ColC BIT
 )

 INSERT INTO @t1
 (
    ResaID
    ,StayDate
    ,ColA
    ,ColB
    ,ColC
 )
 VALUES
 (100, '2020-02-03', 1, 'A', 0)
 ,(100, '2020-02-04', 100, 'B', 1)
 ,(100, '2020-02-05', 255, 'C', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-06', 34, 'D', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-07', 67, 'E', 0)
 ,(120, '2020-04-08', 87, 'F', 0)
 ,(120, '2020-04-09', 545, 'G', 1)
 ,(120, '2020-04-10', 288, 'H', 0)

 INSERT INTO @ranges
 (
    ID
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
 )
 VALUES
 (100, '2020-06-04', '2020-06-07')
 ,(120, '2021-03-01', '2021-03-05');

with
  -- Calculate the date range for each stay in   @t1 .
  ResaRanges as (
    select ResaId, Min( StayDate ) as ResaStartDate, Max( StayDate ) as ResaEndDate
      from @t1
      group by ResaId ),
  -- Match up the   @t1   date ranges with the   @ranges   date ranges.
  CombinedRanges as (
    select RR.ResaId, RR.ResaStartDate, RR.ResaEndDate, DateDiff( day, RR.ResaStartDate, RR.ResaEndDate ) + 1 as ResaDays,
      R.StartDate, R.EndDate, DateDiff( day, R.StartDate, R.EndDate ) + 1 as RangeDays,
      DateDiff( day, RR.ResaStartDate, R.StartDate ) as DaysOffset
      from ResaRanges as RR inner join
        @ranges as R on R.ID = RR.ResaId )
  -- Calculate the new   StayDate   values for all   @t1   ranges that are not longer than the corresponding   @range .
  --   The difference between range starting dates is added to each   StayDate .
  select T.ResaId, T.StayDate, DateAdd( day, CR.DaysOffset, T.StayDate ) as NewStayDate
    from @t1 as T inner join
      CombinedRanges as CR on CR.ResaID = T.ResaID
    where CR.RangeDays >= CR.ResaDays;
-- To see the steps you can use one of the following   select   staements to view the intermediate results:
--   select * from ResaRanges;
--   select * from CombinedRanges;
```